# Eager-loading a tree of entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, eager-loading

I see how to [eager load multiple levels of entities with an include statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eagerLevels).  But what if I'm loading a tree?  Consider this hierarchy of entities:

- Alpha

  - Bravo //a collection

    - Charlie   //a collection
    - Delta  //a collection

Now suppose I want to load Alpha entities that have all Bravo, Charlie, and Delta entities added.  Can this be done with a single `Include` statement?  I suspect the answer is no, but I'd like to be sure.

Otherwise, I suspect I would simply use two `Include` statements.  But even that gives me pause, because it means I would have to reference `Bravo` twice (once per `Include`) statement and I don't know if that confuses EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with two Includes like this:

```
var entities = context.Alphas.Include("Bravos.Charlies")
                             .Include("Bravos.Deltas");
```

Or this:

```
var entities = context.Alphas.Include(a => a.Bravos.Select(b => b.Charlies))
                             .Include(a => a.Bravos.Select(b => b.Deltas));
```

Obviously First is more elegant.

Comment: However the second one is Type-Checked by the compiler which prevents Runtime Exceptions if your models change.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be done with one Include.

You can chain includes like this:

```
var entities = context.Alphas.Include("Bravos").Include("Bravos.Charlies").Include("Bravos.Deltas");
```

Comment: Really? How can you get to all of those entities in one Include? Bravo has two collection properties?

Comment: sorry i didn't see it.But still your code has one extra include.it can be done with two includes `context.Alphas.Include("Bravos.Charlies").Include("Bravos.Deltas");` no need for Bravos, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eagerLevels

Comment: @Selman22: Yes, you are correct. But I wanted to demonstrate that having Bravo in multiple Includes is ok.